# Doxygen: specify a markdown file as the main page

Tags: markdown

I know there seems to be a `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` property which should define a markdown file as the main page, but I tried with doxygen 1.8.5, nothing happened. This markdown file has been specified in `INPUT`, and `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT` is also set to yes. Does anyone have this experience and know how to make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this. `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` has to be the FILE NAME of the Markdown file you are gonna use, which means, FULL PATH will FAIL. I suppose this is a bug existing in the current Doxygen version, so I reported it as [a bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720092).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `md` file needs to be configured in the `INPUT` and `USE_MOFILE_AS_MAINPAGE`.

[Refer this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442157/419348)

Comment: Yes, this was supposed to work, but when the question was asked, there is a bug preventing it from working

Comment: Okay, I got it. I use this feature recently. And I found `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE` needs only `FILE NAME`, no matter where it is. But `INPUT` field needs to include that md file.